# How to use attribute routing in asp.net core when the routing has dot/period in it

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

How to use attribute routing in asp.net core when the routing has dot/period in it.
Complex pattern in asp.net core /.net 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just like normal routing
for example :

```
[Route("/download/v1.3")]
public IActionResult Download()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: will this work in controller/action/   way ? Then how to modify the app.mappath in route table

Comment: @DensityVoidIntense
`app.MapGet("/v1.2", ACTION);`

and 


`app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "dlroute",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{version=1.3}/{action=Index}/{id?}");`